# Is it possible to search cases/documents by user's sid?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, ad

In AD I have a lot of users that may change their personal data.
When I use search by user name obviously I don't get correct results. One solution is to update all necessary items metadata when user changes some data in AD, but I don't want to do that. So is that possible to use search by user's SID? Could You provide me with example Query in ex. SearchQueryTool?
Thanks in advance,
JK.

Comment: You have bad practices in the AD. You should never change the username (you can change the Display Name but username should stay the same) if you change the username you should use migrate-SPUser cmdlet to ensure that new account has access to the old content.